# Should a bias neuron be connected to previous neurons?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I'm trying to add a bias neuron to my neural network that uses the backpropagation algorithm. I'm trying to figure out how I should go about this, should I treat the bias neuron as a regular neuron? which means it's connected to the neurons on the previous layer?

Answer (score 1):

No, bias neurons are not connected to any previous neuron. This is visualized like this:

[image]

([source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/160000/40048))

Answer (score 1):

In a fully connected setting the bias shifts the weighted sum of the previous node output by a certain amount before applying the activation function.

In practice, it's a column vector **b** (bias [initialized as a constant vector]) added to the vector Wx (the product of weight matrix (**W**) and input vector (**x**)) as:

$$\mathrm{Layer2output} = W.\mathrm{Layer1output} +b$$